# share product without login

Tags: product, wishlist, product-view

Currently, when I open a product page, I am presented with three buttons

- Add to Wishlist
- Add to Compare
- And Share

If I click share, it redirects me to a login page.  Why a person needs to be logged in in order to share something, I have no idea.  Is there a reason for this?  Can I fix this?

The only fix I have come up with is to use an extension call AddTo.

Here is a picture
[image]

If I click "Share", I am redirected to login.

Comment: are you talking about the email to a friend feature?

Comment: updated with picture

Comment: what is the url that gets called for the share icon?

Comment: https://mywebsite.com/magento/sendfriend/product/send/id/2691/cat_id/3/

Comment: ok then my answer should work for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the send to a friend feature, this can be activated for guest or only registered users.

In the controller `Mage_Sendfriend_ProductController::preDispatch` it checks to see if the feature is activated only for registered users via `$helper->isAllowForGuest()`

This helper function simply looks for the config value `sendfriend/email/allow_guest` this can be changed via the admin section `Email to a Friend`.

Comment: Seriously, the share button is only used for Email.. damnit.  Your solution did in fact work though.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply - Overwrite - /vendor/magento/module-send-friend/Controller

/* if (!$helper->isAllowForGuest() && !$session->authenticate()) { ---- Before*/

if ($helper->isAllowForGuest() && $session->authenticate()) {  /*-------- After*/